# Pandas Pivot and Group By Don't Match

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Ostensibly the count result of the two functions below should match. However, for some reason they do not.

```
pd.pivot_table(df[['gender','age_group', 'uuid']], index='gender', columns='age_group', aggfunc='count')

df.groupby(['gender', 'age_group']).count()[['uuid']]
```

It seems that the `pd.pivot_table` function is undercounting as if there are nulls in the `uuid` column. There is a NaN column in the `pivot_table` that shouldn't be there, which is where I think all this missing values are going to:

```
age_group   NaN (24.964, 30.0]  (30.0, 35.0]    (35.0, 40.0]    (40.0, 45.0]    (45.0, 50.0]    (55.0, 60.0]
```

However, the `groupby` function seems to be counting correctly as far as I can tell. Any idea what might be causing this?

I am running python 3.7, and it is somewhat new to me (from 3.4) in case that might be the issue.

Comment: Without sample data, it's hard to tell. However, `pivot_table` drops `nan` by default. Try `dropna=False` if things change.

Comment: that was it! maybe post your response so you can get credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pivot_table` drops `nan` by default. Try passing `dropna=False` to `pivot_table` if things change.